# How can I apply black and white clipping on an image with Pillow?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

(**Absolute** image processing newbie here)

I'm trying to apply black and white clipping on an image with **Pillow**. To my understanding I have to adjust the contrast, my question is that is this approach correct?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
image = Image.open('myimage.jpg')
contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
contrast.enhance(2).show()
```

I'm trying to replicate the same functionality in a tool called Color Factory which has the options to set the "Black/White clipping" values to certain percentages.

> The clipping values refer to the amount of pixels that will be clipped
> outside the black and white end points. E.g. if the black clipping
> value has been set to 0,5%, half a percent of the pixels in the image
> will be black.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with alpha trimming? Any pixels that are less than `alpha` or greater than `1 - alpha` (assuming the intensities are normalized) are set to a constant value? Can you show an example?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this question. Lightroom has those two sliders (black clipping / white clipping) which I would like to implement by myself (either opencv, numpy or others...)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of aspects to this:

- find percentiles
- scale values according to the percentiles

The following code should be fairly self-explanatory. It is simplest and fastest to do maths in Numpy or **OpenCV**. Whereas **OpenCV** is likely faster, I didn't want to introduce a new, large library dependency to your project when you already appear to have chosen PIL, so I used Numpy. If speed is important, just say and we can re-work it.

So, to do Photoshop-style contrast enhancement by setting black-point and white-point using percentile clipping:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load low-contrast image
im = Image.open('start.jpg').convert('L')
na = np.array(im)

# Check values
print(f'DEBUG: Min grey: {na.min()}, max grey: {na.max()}')

# Get low (say 1%) and high (say 95%) percentiles
loPct, hiPct = 1.0, 95.0
loVal, hiVal = np.percentile(na, [loPct, hiPct])
print(f'DEBUG: {loPct} percentile={loVal}, {hiPct} percentile={hiVal}')

# Scale image pixels from range loVal..hiVal to range 0..255
res = ((na - na.min()) * 255.0 / (na.max() - na.min())).astype(np.uint8)
Image.fromarray(res).save('result.jpg')
```

**Initial Low Contrast Input Image**

[image]

Copyright © [Mark Setchell](http://www.thesetchells.com) - *Red Top Mountain State Park*

[image]

**Resulting Output Image**

[image]
Copyright © [Mark Setchell](http://www.thesetchells.com) - *Red Top Mountain State Park*

[image]

**Debug Output**

```
DEBUG: Min grey: 66, max grey: 187
DEBUG: 1.0 percentile=78.0, 95.0 percentile=162.00
```

---

Note that you can make a low contrast greyscale from any starting image just in Terminal with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick input.png -colorspace gray +level 30% low-contrast.png
```

Comment: Is the example image you used appropriate for SO's CC-BY-SA license?

Comment: @MarkRansom As far as I know, yes. I understand that use for educational purposes, such as StackOverflow, is deemed *"fair use"*.

Comment: Sure, you may have a right to fair use. But everything posted on SO automatically gets a CC-BY-SA license, and fair use doesn't grant you the right to license.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ok, thank you for giving me a heads-up. I will make some enquiries and see what I can find out - unless you have a reference/link or definitive statement  that you care to share...?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a link.  Wouldn't be surprised if someone has posted about it on Meta though.  I generally sidestep the issue by using my own pictures when I need an example.

Comment: You have currently licensed the image under CC BY-SA 4.0.  It is assumed that you are the original author of this image or that you had the permission to relicense the image. If that is not the case, you should remove the image from the post. You can link to content outside of SO that has different license, and I am pretty sure you can even embed images with different licenses, but you can't upload them to SO as this uses CC BY-SA 4.0 license.

Comment: Thank you @Dharman for your response. I'll do my best to mend my ways as soon as possible.

Comment: @Dharman Would you mind taking a look at my updated answer please? And let me know if it and the copyright notice are appropriate/compliant with SO policy. Then I will update my other inserts. The image is my own. Thank you.

Comment: Beyond SE's [requirements for referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) the situation gets murky fast, due to copyright and licensing being a legal morass which shifts significantly depending on the jurisdiction. As to "fair use", the concept varies from quite strong to non-existent, depending on jurisdiction, with the US in the middle somewhere. In the US, "fair use" claims are *always* litigated, as there's no definitive way to judge them, unless there's already been a very clear case precedent. It also means that giving advice on such skirts close to giving legal advice,

Comment: for which the person giving the advice needs to be a lawyer (in many jurisdictions). I should also note that SE is a commercial operation, so an educational claim with respect to "fair use" is substantially diluted, IMO. When I've wanted to use an image, I've specifically looked for ones which have a compatible license. For me, it's usually been easiest to find something which is in the public domain. There's also a considerable amount of material that's licensed under the Creative Commons (CC) licenses, much of which would be fully compatible.

Comment: I can tell you what I'd *personally* do if I was wanting to make a "fair use" claim to use some images on SO/SE. First, I'd reduce the image size to the minimum at which I felt the image still served my intended educational purpose, as that would have less impact on the commercial viability of the original. In addition to the copyright notation, I'd include a statement something like 'This image is used in this answer under a claim of "fair use". I make no representation that such a "fair use" claim is valid for any other use, nor that the CC BY-SA license extends to the image.'

Answer (score 0):

As I was seeking for the same answer, I tried to get an understanding of black & white clipping in image processing. The following explanation and code is equally applicable for white clipping.

For black clipping you want that a certain range of dark pixels (e.g. 0 up to 10) to be actually black (value 0) instead of black-ish. When assigning 0 to all those values, there will be a gap in the histogram. To overcome this, you transform the remaining pixels values from the range [10...255] to [0...255]

My implementation for RGB images using OpenCV and python looks as follows:

```
def bgr_clipBlack(img, value):
"""Clips the black part of the image. Pixel values ranging [0, value] will be all
clipped to 0 in the resulting image. The image shall be in the BGR format,
value shall be between 0 and 255."""

lut = np.zeros((1, 256), np.uint8)
if value != 255:
    for i in range(value, 256):
        lut[0, i] = ((i - value) * 255) / (255 - value)

return cv2.LUT(img, lut)
```

img is the image read by cv2.imread().
The function clips the values of each of the channels (R, G and B) within [0...value] to 0 and transforms the remaining values from the range [value...255] to [0...255] using a look-up table.
This gave the same results for me as the corresponding Lightroom function.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mark's excellent answer, a slight improvement is to scale in a linear colourspace.

The numeric value in a file like JPG or PNG is not linearly proportional to the amount of light at that point in the scene. Instead, there's a *gamma* applied, meaning a non-linear curve.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction

This is done to improve image quality. Sensors typically have a Poisson noise distribution, so by applying a curve like this, the available 8 bits of data you have are spent more on signal and less on noise.

The consequence for brightening or darkening images is that applying a linear transform to a JPG image, such as:

```
pixel_out = a * pixel_in + b
```

will tend to boost brighter areas more than it should. It's better to transform to a linear space (remove the gamma), then apply a linear scale, then reapply the gamma.

Here's a sample program (using [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) because I'm very familiar with it):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import pyvips

def scale(image, highest):
    """Scale an image so the min value is 0 and the max is "highest"."""
    mx = image.max()
    mn = image.min()
    offset = -mn
    scale = highest / (mx - mn)
    image = (image + offset) * scale

    return image

def linear_scale(image):
    """Scale an image in linear space."""
    image = image.colourspace("scrgb")
    image = scale(image, 1.0)
    image = image.colourspace("srgb")
    
    return image

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])

print("writing non_lin.jpg ...")
non_linear = scale(image, 255.0)
non_linear.write_to_file("non_lin.jpg")

print("writing lin.jpg ...")
linear = linear_scale(image)
linear.write_to_file("lin.jpg")
```

`"scrgb"` colourspace is RGB, but using three floats for each pixel,  0 - 1 for black to white, and linear colourspace (so no gamma). pyvips knows how to apply and remove the regular image gamma for you. You would never write production code like this (you'd compute a single lookup table instead) -- this is just supposed to show the principle.

Here are three images for comparison. Mark's original on the left, non-linear in the centre, and the linear version on the right.

[image: comparison]

You can see the non-linear version (in the center) has become much too contrasty as the bright areas have been boosted too much. The version on the right (the one done in linear space) looks much more like the original.

Comment: I am having difficulties what this answer has to do with the original question about black and white clipping... Gamma correction is a good measure to increase image brightness and this answer is an excellent explanation about it, but I think its off topic for this question.

Comment: As Mark said, the question has two aspects: picking the black and white points, and then rescaling. This answer was supposed to expand on the second aspect and show that scaling in linear space produces noticeably better results.